# Manipulating a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

If I have a long string, lets say

```
var str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean eu accumsan urna. Phasellus imperdiet elementum massa sit amet condimentum. Vivamus porttitor lobortis dignissim. Nam non tellus sapien, at pulvinar augue. Nulla metus mauris, cursus a sodales varius, imperdiet nec nisi. Quisque ut est quis massa sagittis pharetra quis aliquam dui. Phasellus id nisi quis mauris ultricies tristique et ut orci.";
```

and I want to manipulate it to display it something like this

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean eu..."
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You don't need jQuery for that.

Comment: You mean you want to remove the `var str = ` from the beginning and the `;` from the end? Can the variable have a different name than `str`? Please either describe the rules or list more examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with simple javascript string manipulation.

```
var limit = 30 //or wherever you want to cut it off
str = str.substring(0, Math.Min(limit, str.length)) + '...'
```

**EDIT:**
You **do not** need the `Math.Min` as javascript's substring method will take care of the issue if the limit is longer than the string.

**Note:** This will append "..." even if your string is too short and is displayed in its entirety. See [hunter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518015/manipulating-a-string-in-javascript/7518040#7518040) for how to avoid this.

Comment: What browser has the broken implementation of substring which lets you go out of range? The documentation says that if the argument is longer then the string, it should be treated as if it were the string length.

Comment: @Quentin you are right. I was running into this error on a page I was working on, but it was the C# not the javascript. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 6):

Try using the `substring()` method

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

> Returns a subset of a string between one index and another, or through the end of the string.

```
var max = 20;

str = str.length > max 
    ? str.substring(0, max - 3) + "..." 
    : str;
```

Comment: +1 For not appending the "..." when you show the entire string, I overlooked that on my answer.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery, while providing many useful bits of prewritten code, isn't aimed at people doing string manipulation.

Just use [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

```
var truncated = str.substring(0, 40);
if (truncated !== str) {
    str = truncated + "…";
}
```

Comment: @Jim — yes, it does. To quote the page I linked to: "If either argument is greater than stringName.length, it is treated as if it were stringName.length."

Answer (score 0):

You can use [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

```
var limit = 100;
str = str.substring(0,limit) + '...';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var shortStr = str.substr(0, 66) + '...';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn JavaScript then **use** jQuery! All the string manipulation can be done with JavaScript. You should use functions like [`.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) [`.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) and so...

In this case you can use `substr`:

```
str.substr(0, str.indexOf('eu') + 2) + '...';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression replace:

```
str = str.replace(/^(.{0,29}[\w\d])(\b.+)?$/, function($0, $1) {
   if($1.length < str.length) {
       return $1+'...';
   }
   return $0;
});
```

This will:

- If `str` is shorter than 30 characters, the result is the entire string.
- It `str` is longer than 30 characters, it will be cut off at a word boundary and a `...` will be appended to it. This ensures you don't end up with results like `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,...` (with the comma before the `...`)

To change it to truncate at 66 characters...

```
str = str.replace(/^(.{0,65}[\w\d])(\b.+)?$/, function($0, $1) {
   if($1.length < str.length) {
       return $1+'...';
   }
   return $0;
});
```